# How to copy the MySQL database to SQLite

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite

I'm working on a social app on Android ,i'm using MySQL database but i need to have an sqlite database to make my contents appear faster and to have a cache when there is no connection .Is there any way to copy the MySQL database to sqlite and to have all the changes done in sqlite and MySQL ?

Thanks

Comment: just export you DB using some system of manage databases and import the resulting file to SQLite.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ,but when i export from MySQL the extension is .sql how to import it as an SQLite and where do i store it ?

Comment: my friend, sql is Structured Query Language, and it's universal to be used by any RDBMS. Just use some  RDBMS to SQLite and import that file, or run the queries inside the file into RDBMS to SQLite. sorry for my english

Answer (score -1):

Maybe, you could to try to make a query, and extract all the information you want on a auxiliar file, and then, use it for to insert the information at the new database.